# Cleaning up nested if statements

Tags: c#

How could I rewrite this? I'd like to see as many ideas as you can come up with so I can pick one I like. I prefer simple and smart solutions.

```
if (txtName.Text == "")
 {
  txtName.Focus();
 }
 else if (txtSNo.Text == "")
  {
   txtSNo.Focus();
  }
 else if (txtFNo.Text == "")
  {
   txtFNo.Focus();
  }
 else if (txtMNo.Text == "")
  {
   txtMNo.Focus();
  }
 else if (txtEID.Text == "")
  {
   txtEID.Focus();
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I rewrote the question and question title based upon my interpretation of the question. Please edit it if the question now presents a question you didn't want to ask.

Comment: You do not appear to be seeking a review of your code, but rather just a bunch of wild suggestions. Furthermore, you haven't provided much context for the code, so that we don't have much ability to recommend more expressive solutions. Finally, your conditions aren't nested, but rather chained.

Comment: I understand you all, please accept my apologies.

Comment: Please edit your question to be less opinion based if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using some form of collection, then iterating over it to call the `.Text` property, and if it's empty, setting focus and breaking the loop?

The algorithm would be like this: (pseudo code)

```
foreach (var textfield in textfieldList){
    if(textfield.Text == ""){
        textfield.Focus();
        break;
    }
}
```

I'd use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) as the collection to iterate over.

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: @newbie2222 it's pseudo and partial code. You'll have to create the list yourself. You might also have to define the type properly. I'm just giving you the idea on how to rewrite it, as per your question.

Comment: the preferred idiom for checking a string is `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textfield.Text)`